# Erase persistent data from Eclipse/Simulator

Tags: blackberry, simulator, persistent-data

anyone know how to erase the persistent data from the Eclipse tool or from the Blackberry simulator? Resetting the simulator is not erasing the data.

i found these instructions in a book, but i'm thinking that these instructions were for an older version of eclipse.

*"From the JDE Plug-in for Eclipse, you erase the simulator’s file system by selecting the
BlackBerry menu, Erase Simulator File ➤ Erase File System (see Figure 6-6)."*

thanks for your help.

ac

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to erase your application data or resetting the simulator ?
To erase your application data : 
in Eclipse, select Menu -> Blackberry -> erase simulator File -> Erase All

If you want to reset your simulator to it's default state, you must do :

1. Close Eclipse
2. goto where your simulator located.
3. Find clean.bat
4. Run Clean.bat.

Remember you must close eclipse during this process.